# SharePoint SPFx- Not able to use renderListDataAsStream to get random set of paged, sorted and filtered results

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online, spfx

Because of list view threshold error, we planned to use the renderListDataAsStream method to query the SharePoint list. This works to get all the SP list items.

1. How can we get paged results? Using for NextHRef ?Paged=TRUE&p_RequestDate=20210326%2018%3a42%3a17&p_ID=243&PageFirstRow=101&View=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, we can get only the immediate next set of results. Can't we get random results based on page selected?
2. To get filtered results based on search text, tried to pass a query string parameter-
   var queryParams= new Map([["InplaceSearchQuery","xxx"]]);
   return await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(spListName).renderListDataAsStream({
   ViewXml: xml,
   Paging: paging,
   },null,queryParams).then((res) => {
   return res;
   });
   This does not work. How do we get filtered set? Do not want to store all the items in state and use that for filtering as it will be heavy.
   Please recommend any solution options.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pagination works only for next page.
2. I am using filtering (FilterField + FilterValue) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

React table using server filtering and pagination (still in slow development) - https://github.com/Matej4386/Sharepoint/tree/master/m_sptablev2

Comment: Can you provide exact syntax how you are using filterfield+filtervalue. We have first level filtering from the ViewXml. To apply on it, tried as below which does not work-   var queryParams = new Map([["FilterField", "Title"], ["FilterValue", "xxx"]]);
                     return await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(spListName).renderListDataAsStream({
                         ViewXml: xml,Paging: paging},null,queryParams).then((res) => { return res; }); Also will this do exact text match and will it search for all the columns in the list?

Comment: First of all I load possible filters values with this call: _api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/RenderListFilterData?@listUrl=%27%2Fsites%2Fmatejdev%2FLists%2FLibrariesSetting%27&FieldInternalName=Title&ViewId=99642813-26ec-4768-8459-3684d8ba7d56

Comment: Then the call to get filtered values by field Title is: _api/web/lists('6b86a222-ff5e-4251-8932-41b25c9de07f')/RenderListDataAsStream?&FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=XXXX

Comment: It does not work with just FilterField and FilterValue. You have to use FilterField1 and FilterValue1, ...

Comment: Thank you @Matej. So this is kind of displaying filter value options(probably context or flyout) and not search textbox kind, and based on user selection, the results are filtered. Providing user input also should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a helper class for list item pagination using renderListDataAsStream, here is the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mgwdev-m365-helpers
You can use SPListItemCamlPagedDataProvider class for list item pagination

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. I checked the SPListItemCamlPagedDataProvider helper class. I believe to get the pagination details we need to make a query to the list to fetch the items, them only we can determine next.

Comment: Yes, it's already implemented there. If You would like to check out the implementation details (or maybe just copy the code) You can find it here:
https://github.com/mgwojciech/mgwdev-m365-helpers/blob/main/src/dal/dataProviders/SPListItemCamlPagedDataProvider.ts
If You want to check out more usage of it You can find it in unit tests here:
https://github.com/mgwojciech/mgwdev-m365-helpers/blob/main/tests/dal/dataProviders/SPListItemPagedDataProvider.test.ts